# Finding ratio of water to air in a closed container

Tags: homework-and-exercises, density

Say that you have a container which is completely sealed off. There's some liquid with some unknown density on the bottom and air on the top. How can you find the density of the liquid? Simple physics concepts are preferred.

Edit: Let's say that the container is 3 cm, and the thickness of the container is 1 cm for easy calculations. It's also made out of aluminum, the volume is 300 mL, and the mass is 350g.

Edit #2: Here was my approach for solving this:
I tried to use some simple density equations, like Mass = VcanDcan + VliquidDliquid + (Vtotal-Vcan-Vliquid)Dair and tried to solve a system of equations. However, I was unable to find another equation to solve it. The other equations that I found were just variations of the equation said above.

Comment: How much more do you know about the container?  Do you know the material of the container?  Do you know its dimensions?  Do you know how thick the walls of the container are?  Is there only one container, or do you have other containers that have more or less liquid in them?

Comment: @DavidWhite , I made some changes to my problem. Hope that helps.

Comment: Your question is looking better now than it was, but it is still absolutely mandatory for questions of this nature that you show your _own_ efforts/thoughts/attempts at solving the problem _first_.

Comment: What thoughts do you have about this problem? How do you think it might be solved?

Comment: @BLAZE I've added my approach to the post.

Answer (score 1):

If you know all dimensions of the container and its mass, you may weigh the container to determine its mass with the liquid and measure the level of the liquid using an ultrasonic level meter. Alternatively, if the container has a simple form, one can estimate the internal volume that is free from liquid by knocking at the container and measuring the resonance sound frequency.